# Deleted my own question a few minutes ago and I regret it, is it lost forever?

Tags: support, questions

Is there a way to restore the question?

Answer (score 6):

I assume you mean [How to add a directory tree to a ClearCase repository in-place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247154/how-to-add-a-directory-tree-to-a-clearcase-repository-in-place) on Stack Overflow, so I restored it for you.

Comment: any way to ask for such a thing other than post here? Obviously, you have nothing to flag and no PM system that I'm aware of. Just curious to know, if I'll ever need such thing. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: No, unfortunately I don't think there's a good way.  Some alternatives might be to flag one of your other posts, try to find a moderator in chat, or just repost the question.  None of those seem great to me, but at least you have options.  :)

Comment: Thanks @Bill - maybe it's worth adding something similar to the *Formatting Sandbox* to allow people to request such things? You see any potential in such request, as moderator yourself?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: That would be better than having individual meta posts any time it came up.  People could leave an answer to let us know what the deleted question was, then flag it for us here.

Answer (score 2):

No, your question is not gone forever, moderators can still restore it.

There's no official way currently to alert a moderator to the issue since you cannot flag the deleted question, but you do have several other options:

- Flag another post and link to the deleted question
- Find a moderator in chat
- Repost the question
- Make a post here

Answer (score 1):

A moderator should be able to restore it.

Comment: The question is - what is the correct process to inform a moderator of this since there is no way to flag it?  A post here seems to be a bit much (though it's obviously effective!)

Comment: @Daniel exactly what I asked Bill above :)

Comment: @Shadow Yeah so I just made a CW post with his response as it's the current options available